# Change preg matchess with numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to replace the matches with numbers by sorting them but couldn't do it. I have a string that has {} in between words. I'd like to change them to 1, 2, 3, etc. without foreach. could be with **preg matches all**?

```
$string = 'sample {} test {} string {}';
```

This string must have seen like this:
sample (0) test (1) string (2)

This is my code:

```
$string_split = explode('{}', $string);
foreach($string as $string_word){
  $i ++;
  echo $string_word . $i . ' ';
}
```

Comment: Could to clarify your question declaring what kind of answer you want?

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I'm trying to replacing {}'s with (0) (1) (2) numbers by sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), incrementing the count for every replacement.

```
$string = 'sample {} test {} string {}';
$count = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback("~{}~", function($m) use (&$count) {
    return '(' . $count++ . ')';
}, $string);
```

Output

```
sample (0) test (1) string (2)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IDHlh)

Comment: @AlivetoDie You are right, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate over your string using `preg_match`, keeping a counter along the way:

```php
$string = 'sample {} test {} string {}';
$counter = 0;
while (preg_match("/\{\}/", $string)) {
    $string = preg_replace("/\{\}/", "(" . $counter . ")", $string, 1);
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}

echo "\n" . $string;
```

This prints:

```
sample {} test {} string {}
sample (0) test (1) string (2)
```

Comment: Now it's perfect.+1. deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking the regex can be useful.

```
$re = '/(.*?)\s{}(\s?)/m';
$str = 'sample {} test {} string {}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result

$new_string = null;
$i = 0;

foreach($matches as $item){
    $new_string .=  $item[1] . ' ('. $i . ') ';
    $i++;
}

echo $new_string;
```

Output:

```
sample (0) test (1) string (2)
```